# installation path for sqlite database

Tags: python

I am trying to access a database using python. The src folder is:

```
ptbl/
├── dialogue.py
├── elem_H.py
├── elems.db
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
├── main.py
├── menubar.ui
└── menu.py
```

with `elem_H.py` access `elems.db` database as:

```
sqlfile = "elems.db"
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlfile)
```

Ofcourse, when I am running it from terminal, inside src dir(ptbl), everything works fine. 
But, when I am outside the `src` dir,its giving error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Overview
```

and same, if I install it using `autotools`.

For elems.db to be worked,I have to run it from a folder where elems.db is present.

How can I make it installed in a path?

Comment: Is `elems.db` 'embedded' in your application or can it exist somewhere else?

Comment: its a separate file, so it can exist anywhere.

Comment: Then you should make `sqlfile` a configurable parameter. Pass it as a command line argument or read it from a configuration file. Then you can make the path to it absolute.

Comment: sorry, but that db should not be user accessible. It should be copied to install dir at the installatime.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing python and SQLite files in one single directory is not a good pratice at all. You should fix it and extract `elems.db` from your libraries directory.

Moreover, as Lutz Horn said in comments, you should make it configurable and not trust that your database file will be always located in the exact same place.

But anyway, to fix your issue without updating these two points, you have to take care of the `elem_H.py` location. You know `elems.db` is next to it, so you can do:

```
import os.path
sqlfile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "elems.db")
```

- `__file__` store the relative path to your file from the place where you run command.
- [os.path.dirname](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) remove the filename from the given path.
- [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) will concat the computed path and your filename.